# How can I translate the word "responsiveness" into Brazilian Portuguese?

Tags: português-brasileiro, tradução-inglês, tradução

In a context like this:

> The mobile **responsiveness** of this app is horrible!

And a related example like this:

> Let's make this entire mobile app **responsive**

How can we translate the word "**responsiveness**" by itself into Brazilian Portuguese?

Comment: com capacidade de resposta, reativo

Comment: The questions that the OP asks are consistently lacking details. He provides too little information about context and concrete examples. This question is unclear on wheter you want to translate responsive or resposiveness. If you want to translate resposivenes you should clearly state so and provide at least one example of usage in English. Ideally that would be the setence that you really want to translate.

Comment: @Hugo that was constructive criticism from Bruno. Your response was not.

Comment: @Dan Getz, towards who? I don't see how one person can all of the sudden use one question to come bashing at all of the questions pertaining to a user saying that they lack everything that is needed to be considered a question and is constantly doing everything wrong! It's like he is calling the user a retarded person in polite terminology. Anyways, it can be constructive from your perspective but all he clearly did was try to diminish the user.

Comment: Hugo, while @BrunoCosta's tone might have been harsher than you would have preferred, try to focus on the message, not on how it was delivered. I have answered a few of your questions (you can check them out), and, several times, I have struggled to write them without turning them into an 1,000 words essay. I understand you might be in a hurry, but you will get better, faster answers from us if you spend a little more time detailing them.

Comment: Thanks RamonMelo! Next question I post, I will for sure take some additional time to elaborate. - Now this is what we call constructive criticism. @BrunoCosta , Dan Getz.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective **responsivo** is being used to refer to **responsive UI**.
We can separate "responsive" from "adaptive", so, despite it not being a very common word, it will be immediately associated with responsive layouts in applications.

**responsivo** (masculine) – layouts

**responsiva** (feminine) – applications

Comment: Acho que o Hugo quer «responsiveness» e não «responsive». Certo Hugo?

Comment: @JorgeB.  Yes. I edited the question to better clarify with a proper example. Thanks! 
Thanks Carlos Martins!

Comment: The mobile responsiveness of this app is horrible! A responsividade deste aplicativo de celular está horrível! A capacidade de resposta / de responder deste aplicativo de celular está horrível!

Comment: @AndréLyra na verdade não se trata de resposta mas sim de a app se adaptar a diversos tamanhos de tela.

Comment: Mas pode ser isso, a resposta aos comandos de tela. Com relação a web design achei Design Responsivo no google.

Comment: This particular word is atrocious. It is commonly used, though, so I guess it qualifies as a good answer, but I wonder if the webdev/mobile dev communities actually searched for a proper Portuguese word before incorporating this anglicism to the language.

Comment: O comportamento reacional desse dispositivo de comunicação está horrível

Answer (score 0):

I think Interactive fits good to it too.
"Interativo" in portuguese (BR), because the direct translation of "responsiveness" is "responsividade" which is not very used here, it still understandable but it is never used.

When we think about response we think also to interactiveness, to "talk" to the user, communicate with them. I think "Interativo" fits to your question.

"The mobile responsiveness of this app is horrible!"

"A Interatividade desse celular é terrível!"

"Let's make this entire mobile app responsive"

"vamos fazer esse app mais interativo!"

Hope it helps

Comment: I agree with all your premises, but, unfortunately, _interatividade_ is already reserved to describe another set of behaviors.

Comment: Ele quer que o software reaja bem se adaptando. Interatividade não tem a ver com isso.